# Is there any limit for source in typeahead?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typeahead

I am using JQuery typeahed from [RunningCoder](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/). Typeahead works well if I have few records in my source, but does not work if my source has around 500 records.

It is not related to the result count, which can be managed by `maxItem` parameter. Also, there is no issue in getting the JSON string from the server, as I can print it without any issue.

I know ideally, I should not have them in my page pre-loaded and search it based on the input, but in my case hitting the server for search is not an option and I want to perform the search from the static data I have in my view. Here is my code:

```
$.typeahead({
                input: "#List .typeahead",
                minLength: 3,
                templateValue: "{{Text}}",
                display: ["Text", "Subtext"],
                emptyTemplate: 'No results for "{{query}}"',
                template: '<span>' +
                    '<span class="result" id="{{Value}}">{{Text}}</span>' +
                    '</span>',
                source: {
                    Issuer: {
                      data: @Html.Raw(Model.EveryThing)
                    }
                }
            });
```

In my code above if `Model.Everything` has 40-50 records then it works fine, but does not work for around 500 records.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
After figuring out the issue, would like to explain it a bit as this may help someone. By using above code, you can search the list based on two fields i.e. `Text` and `Subtext`, but the user will see only Text in the result and then can select from matching options. This will be very useful if you want to perform the search on more than one field but show just one field.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after creating sample data on my own, rather than relying on server response. The issue is not with the length of the result, but null entries in the result.
In my data, there are few objects with `Subtext` as NULL, and that causes the issue, I fixed it by replacing the NULL with an empty string, and this works as expected now.